# Javascript - Group AND sort (by date) array elements

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array with objects like this:

```
[
  {date: 2023-05-06, group: 'groupA'},
  {date: 2023-05-05, group: 'group1'},
  {date: 2023-05-07, group: 'groupA'},
  {date: 2023-05-08, group: 'group1'},
]
```

I would like to get an array where the newest element is the first and the elements are grouped by the `group` property which is a string.

Expected result:

```
[
  {date: 2023-05-08, group: 'group1'},  // newest in array
  {date: 2023-05-05, group: 'group1'},  // second newest in same group
  {date: 2023-05-07, group: 'groupA'},  // second newest in array
  {date: 2023-05-06, group: 'groupA'},  // second newest in same group
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We'd create a `groupBy` function to allow us to group any array by an arbitrary key.

We'll sort our input by date first then group.

Finally we'll get all values and flatten using [Object.values()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) and [Array.flat()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat):

```js
const input = [
  {date: '2023-05-06', group: 'groupA'},
  {date: '2023-05-05', group: 'group1'},
  {date: '2023-05-07', group: 'groupA'},
  {date: '2023-05-08', group: 'group1'},
]

function groupBy(input, key) {
    return input.reduce((acc, el) => { 
        acc[el[key]] = acc[el[key]] || [];
        acc[el[key]].push(el);
        return acc;
    }, {});
}

// Group by 'group', but sort first...
const inputSortedByDate = input.sort((a,b) => Date.parse(b.date) - Date.parse(a.date));
const grouped = groupBy(inputSortedByDate, 'group');

// Get flattened result...
const result = Object.values(grouped).flat();
console.log('Result:', result)
```

Comment: But the OP wants latest entry first like, `2023-05-08` should come first

Comment: Too many JavaScript functions for such a simple problem i.e. sort array by two columns. First you iterate the data multiple times using reduce (which is [misused](https://dev.to/jasterix/is-reduce-bad-2hhd)), values and flat (which itself is nested loops); then there is sort. It should have been kept simple.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the result exempel you provided, I think this would work for you.

You can solve this by grouping by `group` and sorting each group individually. Then you can sort the resulted groups. Finally, you can merge the sorted groups in a single array (this should keep the array sorted because you are iterating it by order)

```js
const input = [
    { date: '2023-05-06', group: 'groupA' },
    { date: '2023-05-05', group: 'group1' },
    { date: '2023-05-07', group: 'groupA' },
    { date: '2023-05-08', group: 'group1' },
];

// stage 1: group
const grouped = {};
input.forEach((el) => {
    if (grouped[el.group] && grouped[el.group].length > 0) {
        grouped[el.group].push(el);
    } else {
        grouped[el.group] = [el];
    }
});

// stage 2: sort group elements by date (in group)
const sortedInGroupes = Object.values(grouped).map((el) => {
    return el.sort((a, b) => new Date(b.date).getTime() - new Date(a.date).getTime());
});

// stage 3: sort groupes by date (globally)
const sortedGroupes = sortedInGroupes.sort((a, b) => new Date(b[0].date).getTime() - new Date(a[0].date).getTime());

// stage 4: merge sorted groupes
const output = [];
sortedGroupes.forEach((grp) => output.push(...grp));
console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 0):

I used array.sort to achieve this.

```js
const input = [
  {date: '2023-05-06', group: 'groupA'},
  {date: '2023-05-05', group: 'group1'},
  {date: '2023-05-07', group: 'groupA'},
  {date: '2023-05-08', group: 'group1'},
]

const sortedArray = input.sort((a, b) => {
const dateA = new Date(a.date);
const dateB = new Date(b.date);

// Sort by date in descending order
if (dateA > dateB) {
  return -1;
} else if (dateA < dateB) {
  return 1;
}

// If dates are equal, sort by group in ascending order
if (a.group < b.group) {
  return -1;
} else if (a.group > b.group) {
  return 1;
}
return 0;
});

console.log('Result:', sortedArray)
```

Comment: It does not cover my use case because it only sorts by date and does not groups objects.

Answer (score 0):

this could be solved by ordering the collection by date, and then grouping them via group name;

```
const input = [
    { date: '2023-05-06', group: 'groupA' },
    { date: '2023-05-05', group: 'group1' },
    { date: '2023-05-07', group: 'groupA' },
    { date: '2023-05-08', group: 'group1' },
];

function orderBy(x, fn, order = 'asc') {  
    return x.sort((a, b) => {
        const aT = fn(a);
        const bT = fn(b);

        if (order == 'asc') {
            return bT - aT;   
        }
        return aT - bT;
    }); 
}

function groupBy(x, groupName) {
    return x.sort((a, b) => {
        if (a[groupName] < b[groupName]) {
            return -1;
        } else if (a[groupName] > b[groupName]) {
            return 1;
        }

        return 0;
    })
}


groupBy(
  orderBy(input, (o) => new Date(o.date).getTime()),
  'group'
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `String.localeCompare()` but realize that you need `group` and `date` in opposing order; `group` in ascending but `date` in descending order.

```js
const
      input = [
        {date: "2023-05-06", group: 'groupA'},
        {date: "2023-05-05", group: 'group1'},
        {date: "2023-05-07", group: 'groupA'},
        {date: "2023-05-08", group: 'group1'},
      ],

      output = input.sort(
          (a,b) => `${a.group} ${b.date}`.localeCompare(`${b.group} ${a.date}`)
      );
      
console.log( output );
```